# Бинарное дерево

Tags: c++, дерево

На вход подается описание бинарного дерева. На листьях (висячих вершинах) этого дерева написаны целые числа (от -10^6 до 10^6). Идем от корня дерева, случайно поварачивая направо или налево (с вероятностями 0.5).

Чему равно cреднее значение числа на листе, в который мы в конечном счете придем? Ответ вывести с точностью до двух знаков после запятой.

Грамматика дерева:

```
tree -> leaf

tree -> (tree tree)

leaf -> integer
```

Можно решить без дерева, вот решение:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str,st;

    int index = 0,k=0,i=0;
    double s=0,res=0;
    res = 0;
    char chr;
    getline(cin,str);

    while (index < str.length())
    {
        chr = str[index];

        if ((chr == '1') || (chr == '2') || (chr == '3') || (chr == '4') || (chr == '5') || (chr == '6') || (chr == '7') || (chr == '8') || (chr == '9') || (chr == '10') )
            {
                st = chr;
                k = atoi(st.c_str()); cout << "k=" << k << endl;
                res = res + k*pow(0.5, s); cout << "s=" << s << endl;
            }

        if (chr == '(')
        {
            s = s+1 ;

        }
        if (chr == ')')
        {
            s = s-1;

        }
        cout << "ravn" << res<<endl;

        index++;
    }
        cout << "ravn" << res;
        system("pause");
}
```

Только я не пойму, как сделать так, чтобы распознавать все числа. Подскажите.

Comment: @klach, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Поправил..

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно средневзвешенное значение в листе. Весом является вероятность попасть в данный лист (то есть, очевидно, два в степени (минус глубина листа)). Далее очевидно.

**Обновление**

[[[[@klach](/users/25195/klach)](/users/25195/klach)](/users/25195/klach)](/users/25195/klach): Ну да, нужно реализовать само дерево.

Если вы до этого никогда не работали с деревьями, сначала почитайте об этом (информации валом). Дерево есть

- значение в корне
- левое поддерево
- правое поддерево

То есть выходит очевидная структура данных:

```
struct tree
{
    int value;
    tree* left;
    tree* right;
};
```

Как именно с ней работать, объяснять долго, посмотрите в книгах (или попробуйте сами в качестве лёгкого упражнения).

**Обновление**

[[[[@klach](/users/25195/klach)](/users/25195/klach)](/users/25195/klach)](/users/25195/klach): Ох. Ну, я вам здесь не смогу рассказать содержимое книги. Смотрите. Если у вас вот такое дерево:

```
  /\
 /\ 3
1  2
```

то его можно сконструировать так:

```
tree* root = new tree();
// правое поддерево - лист
tree* r = new tree();
r->value = 3;
root->right = r;
// левое поддерево содержит два подподдерева
tree* l = new tree();
tree* ll = new tree(); 
ll->value = 1;
tree* lr = new tree();
lr->value = 2;
l->left = ll;
l->right = lr;
root->left = l;
```

Обработку деревьев проще всего вести рекурсивно. Вот, например, функция, подсчитывающая количество листьев:

```
int numberofleaves(tree* t)
{
    if (t->left == nullptr && t->right == nullptr) // лист
        return 1;
    else
        return numberofleaves(t->left) + numberofleaves(t->right);
}
```

Comment: @VladD,Совсем никогда не работал с деревьями. Задачу понял. На вход подается описание бинарного дерева. Как это реализовать в код? Я должен реализовать само дерево? Объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: @VladD, не могу ничего хорошего найти. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы она заполнялось вот так: (2 3(1 4)).

Comment: Нужно ли мне описывать действия с деревом?

Comment: Обработку деревьев проще всего вести рекурсивно. Вот, например, функция, подсчитывающая количество листьев:

    int numberofleaves(tree* t)
    {
        if (t->left == nullptr && t->right == nullptr) // лист
            return 1;
        else
            return numberofleaves(t->left) + numberofleaves(t->right);
    }